# Append value by key path

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to mutate object. How can I append value by key path (e.g. 'arr.1.bar')?
Feels like there is a simpler solution:

```js
const key1 = 'foo';
const key2 = 'arr.1.bar';
const obj = {
  foo: 2,
  arr: [{
    bar: 1
  }, {
    bar: 2
  }],
};

const appendVal = (ref, key, val) => {
  key.split('.').reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (acc[el] && typeof acc[el] === 'object')
      return acc[el];
    acc[el] = val;
  }, ref);
};

appendVal(obj, key1, 3)
appendVal(obj, key2, 3)

console.log(obj); // { foo: 3, arr: [ { bar: 1 }, { bar: 3 } ] }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path